# Post data isn't be sent with jquery / django

Tags: django, jquery, post

I'm trying to perform a simple post to django that will take in a variable and then redirect the user to another page. Right now, my javascript looks like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
  type: "POST",
  url: "{% url unity.survey.views.post %}",
  data: {  // <-- error here?
    'order' : '1', 
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}' 
  },
  success: function(datas) {
    if (datas.redirect) {
      window.location.href = data.redirect;
    }

  }
  });
 };
```

My corresponding view in django looks like so:

```
def post(request, *args, **kwargs):
  if 'order' in request.POST:
    order = request.POST['order']
  else:          
    return redirect('unity.survey.views.login')

  .... some calculations with order ....
  return render_to_response(
     'template.html', 
      some_dictionary, 
      context_instance=RequestContext(request)
  )
```

For some reason, it appears that nothing is sent to the view. Looking at Firefox's web console, I see:

```
[07:31:12.414] POST http://127.0.0.1/unity/ survey/ [undefined 17ms]
[07:31:12.422] GET http://127.0.0.1/unity/survey/ [HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND 73ms]
[07:31:12.497] GET http://127.0.0.1/unity/survey/login [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 177ms]
```

It just redirects me to the login page regardless of what I do. I've tried using .post instead of .ajax, but it results in the same thing. Any idea why this might be the case? I have a similar function and it works great but for some reason I can't get this to work. It just appears as if no POST data is being sent.

Comment: You have a typo in `window.location.href = data.redirect;` shouldn't it be `datas.redirect`?

Comment: Is that your whole view? It doesn't send any response in case there is an "order" field in the data sent.

Comment: No its not the whole view... the rest of it does some calculations with the order variable before redirecting to a different page. The point is that order is never retrieved- it just goes straight to login.

Comment: Yep, that `undefined` is a clear signal there. That means no response/response code was sent. Which like @lqc says, is because when `order` is in the POST dict, no response is sent.

Comment: Please see my edit- order is used to determine which page to render. If it can't find "order" in POST, it returns to a login page.

Comment: Are you sure there is no error in URL? Note the space before `survey`. `http://127.0.0.1/unity/ survey/`

Comment: Well, your response now is a HTML document, which is fine if you're just going to dump it as-is into the document, but you're trying to introspect `datas` to see if a `redirect` key has been set. For that, you need to return a JSON response.

Comment: what does `print request.POST` say?